# URL defined by config.action_cable.url generating 404 when consumed by Vue frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, websocket, actioncable

In my `config/environments/development.rb` file, I've added

`config.action_cable.url = "ws://lab.lizardgizzards.com:4001/cable"`

Using a Vue module called `actioncable-vue` I'm attempting to have my Vue frontend consume the Action Cable API that I'm creating in Rails.

This is the error I see in my browser console on the vue frontend:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://lab.lizardgizzards.com:4001/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

I do get a response from `http://lab.lizardgizzards.com:4001`

Answer (score 0):

The fix was pretty simple, just needed to add this to `config/environments/development.rb`:

`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]`